# Trying to write OpenVINO inference engine but input image astype to FP16 get ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, openvino

I tried this [tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tutorial-on-how-to-run-inference-with-openvino-in-2021-a96e5e7c99f8) to create my own inference engine with OpenVINO. When I try to create random input data to the inference_request, it can work normally.

```
random_input_data = np.random.randn(1, 3, 224, 224).astype(np.float16)
tensor_description = TensorDesc(precision="FP16", dims=(1, 3, 224, 224), layout='NCHW')
input_blobs = Blob(tensor_description, random_input_data)
```

But if I replace random_input_data with my real image path

```
random_input_data = np.array(r"C:\MyImagePath\XXX.png").astype(np.float16)
```

I get the error message

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'C:\\MyImagePath\\XXX.png'
```

Why I cannot `astype` my real image to FP16?
(I use Windows 10 with openvino_2021.4.689)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cv2.imread("image.png") instead.

I recommend that you refer to the official OpenVINO documentation:
[Integrate Inference Engine with Your Python Application](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Integrate_with_customer_application_new_API.html?sw_type=switcher-python)

Please bear in mind that you'll need to exactly know the model's input shape, its layout, and the input data precision (FP32/FP16/etc) to get the correct output